# How to get Block Cipher ECB key given cipher text and plaintext

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key, brute-force, ecb

This seems like a really simple problem. I just can't seem to figure it out. 
A message was encrypted using a Block Cipher that seems to follow an Electronic Codebook method. I know that they took it in blocks of 3 characters at a time. I know what the message says and I know what the cipher text says; but I want to know the keys. The problem says that it was encrypted using the same method twice but with different keys. Is it possible to find the keys without brute forcing it?

If not, then how would I minimize the time needed to brute force the key?

BTW: The key is in hex and it can only be 6 characters long maximum. So the biggest key possible in decimal would be 16777215

Comment: And your intention is? I hope it is not something related to hacking.

Comment: it is a cryptographic problem that someone posted... it is related to hacking, but the problem was supposed to be hacked. Nobody actually used ECB to encrypt their data. Plus, you almost never have both the plaintext and the cipher text.

Comment: @PranavJain That last statement is wrong, having both plaintext and cipher text is extremely common as a message almost never consists of random characters in real life.

Comment: You need to implement a meet in the middle attack here. Try it and come back if your implementation keeps failing after debugging.

Comment: But doesn't it require a lot of resources to store and run all 16777215 options twice

Comment: Ok... I tried it, and outputted the results of the encryption and decryption into two separate text files... how do I find the similar lines with minimal compute time.